# Set Preproccessor directive for only one program in Automake file

Tags: c, makefile, c-preprocessor, automake

Let us assume that we have a source file "a.c".

The "a.c" source file is used in building programs "Prog1","Prog2", and 'Prog3".

```
"Prog1" also uses source file "x.c"
"Prog2" uses source file "y.c"
"Prog3" uses source file "z.c"
```

Assume that "a.c" uses a function called "foo()" that is only defined in "x.c".  Hence "Prog1" would get built, but "Prog2" and "Prog3" would not compile.

Also assume that "a.c" needs to call function bar1() when building program Prog1, bar2() when building program Prog2, and bar3() when building program Prog3.

How should we create the automake Makefile.am to support this?

I have been trying to specify distinct preprocessor directives when building each program in the automake file "Makefile.am", but so far could not see how it is done.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Show us your attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution? Create three different rules for three different object files all built from the `a.c` source file.

Then each rule can easily add extra flags needed for the specific build.

Answer (score 0):

```
bin_PROGRAMS = prog1 prog2 prog3

prog1_SOURCES = a.c x.c
prog1_CPPFLAGS = -DPROG1

prog2_SOURCES = a.c y.c
prog2_CPPFLAGS = -DPROG2

prog3_SOURCES = a.c z.c
prog3_CPPFLAGS = -DPROG3
```

But to use this you need to make sure you call `AM_PROG_CC_C_O` in your `configure.ac`, since `a.c` is then compiled three times with different options.